# Placeholder for TreeView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, treeview

I have a TreeView which is empty at the start and I want to set a placeholder until it is empty. Like the one available for ListView (setPlaceholder())

My first thought was to wrap the TreeView into a BorderPane and just change the center based on the number of elements in the TreeView. The problem is though that I add elements to the TreeView through drag and drop and if I set a label to the center for substituting a placeholder, I won't be able to drag n drop my items in the TreeView anymore. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Apply the same drag & drop functionality to the `Label` as well?

Comment: How the data would get into the ListView if I drag n drop it on the label?

Comment: I guess that depends on how you've implemented the drag & drop for the `TreeView`. Are you not manually setting the `TreeView` contents somehow?

Comment: Does making your placeholder [mouse transparent](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty) help?

Comment: when would you consider the treeView to be empty? null root? no children in the root? Anyway, you need a custom TreeViewSkin that adds the placeholder (or toggles its visibilty) when its emptyness changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeView has no placeholder support - not entirely certain, why not, but could be that an empty tree (whatever that means: null root? root without children? root not showing?) is a rare species.

It's rather simple to implement, though, by following the implementation for a virtualized control that supports it, f.i. TableView. All we need is a custom TreeViewSkin that

- manages (creates and adds to the tree's hierarchy, layouts as needed) the placeholder
- listens to relevant state of the tree and updates the placeholder's visibilty as appropriate

An example, toggling the emptyness by toggling the tree's root between null/not null via a button:

```
public class TreeViewWithPlaceholder extends Application {


    private static class TreeViewPlaceholderSkin<T> extends TreeViewSkin<T> {

        private StackPane placeholderRegion;
        private Label placeholderLabel;

        public TreeViewPlaceholderSkin(TreeView<T> control) {
            super(control);
            installPlaceholderSupport();
        }

        private void installPlaceholderSupport() {
            registerChangeListener(getSkinnable().rootProperty(), e -> updatePlaceholderSupport());
            updatePlaceholderSupport();
        }

        /**
         * Updating placeholder/flow visibilty depending on whether or not the tree
         * is considered empty. 
         * 
         * Basically copied from TableViewSkinBase.
         */
        private void updatePlaceholderSupport() {
            if (isTreeEmpty()) {
                if (placeholderRegion == null) {
                    placeholderRegion = new StackPane();
                    placeholderRegion.getStyleClass().setAll("placeholder");
                    getChildren().add(placeholderRegion);

                    placeholderLabel = new Label("No treeItems");
                    placeholderRegion.getChildren().setAll(placeholderLabel);
                }
            }
            getVirtualFlow().setVisible(!isTreeEmpty());
            if (placeholderRegion != null)
                placeholderRegion.setVisible(isTreeEmpty());
        }


        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
            super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);
            if (placeholderRegion != null && placeholderRegion.isVisible()) {
                placeholderRegion.resizeRelocate(x, y, w, h);
            }
        }

        private boolean isTreeEmpty() {
            return getSkinnable().getRoot() == null;
        }

    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>() {

            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new TreeViewPlaceholderSkin<>(this);
            }

        };

        Button toggle = new Button("toggleRoot");
        toggle.setOnAction(e -> {
            TreeItem<String> root = tree.getRoot();
            tree.setRoot(root == null ? new TreeItem<>("root") : null);
        });
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(tree);
        content.setBottom(toggle);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        //stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TreeViewWithPlaceholder.class.getName());

}
```